# Looping through all the possibilities

Tags: javascript, arrays

So what I am trying to do is loop through arrays to create all the possible combinations.

```js
let array = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'];
let length = 8;
```

I want to end up with an array of all possibilities with each element being string of 8 characters length like this:

```
let result = ['ABCDEFAB', 'ABCDEFAC', 'ABCDEFAD'];
```

Can't wrap my head around this. Pairing was much easier, this - I can't think of anything

Comment: is `'AAAAAAAA'` valid? have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, all the possibilities within the array are valid. I've tried using for loop but can't come up with proper way to use it here. I'm not advanced with JS yet (as basic as this example might be), sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force method. I am calculating 6^8 permutations which is 1,679,616. Might not be a good idea to just plain run this without limits. The html is there to be able to look at the results. Not really part of your question.

The jQuery is only about the display, so can be ignored :)

```html
<ul id="thelist">
</ul>
```

```js
    const a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
    var tot = 0;

    a.forEach(function (a1) {
        a.forEach(function (a2) {
            a.forEach(function (a3) {
                a.forEach(function (a4) {
                    a.forEach(function (a5) {
                        a.forEach(function (a6) {
                            a.forEach(function (a7) {
                                a.forEach(function (a8) {
                                    if (tot++ < 150) {
                                        $('#thelist').append(`<li>${a1}${a2}${a3}${a4}${a5}${a6}${a7}${a8}</li>`);
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and use an array of indices and update this array for each `next()` call.

```js
function* generate(symbols, length) {
    let indices = Array.from({ length }, _ => 0),
        index = length - 1,
        j = index;

    while (j >= 0) {
        yield indices.map(i => symbols[i]).join('');
        indices[index]++;
        j = index;
        while (indices[j] >= symbols.length) {
            indices[j] = 0;
            indices[--j]++;
        }
        if (j < index) index = length - 1;
    }
}

console.log([...generate('ABCD', 5)]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```